# How to iterate a loop in a flow

Tags: visual-workflow, loop

I am very new to flows and I'm not yet still familiar with its workings.
So I have flow that has a loop that supposed to iterate depending on the User's decision.

As you can see from the image below, after the creation of a custom object called "Delivery Note", I want to create multiple child objects called "Delivery Note Item" under it.

I was thinking that I could create a loop that will only terminate if I say I no longer want to create new Delivery Note Items. However, when I debug this flow, the loop will just end because the collection variable I set on the Loop is empty.

Most of the loops I see is that they first have a "Get Records" before the loop to add records to a collection and then use that collection to iterate the loop.

How can I do this when the Delivery Note Items are still to be created?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Is your question solved or do you need some more explanation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use the loop element, build the loop with the decision element :)
[image]

I hope this helps :)

Comment: hi sorry for the late reply. Yes, this is a great help for us! Actually, this never occurred to me to not use a loop. Your solution is very elegant and I thank for this. XD

Answer (score 0):

To avoid governor limits, don't put create records elements inside a loop. This will do the same thing, but be more scalable: Input screen > Assign to collection variable > Decision > return to input screen if yes, Create Records if no (outside the loop) > next step. The delivery note records you collect in the collection variable get written in one transaction at the end.